# Writing a loop to apply ifelse for each column individually (in R)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to writing loops and have been trying hard to figure this out myself.

I have a dataframe where a unique threshold needs to be applied over each column individually. If the value is higher than the threshold, then the original value is kept. If it is lower, it will be converted to 0.

This is just a trimmed down dataframe `Data.t` as an example.

```
         Peptide.1 Peptide.2 Peptide.3
MF.001      -0.01      0.04      0.04
MF.006       0.02      0.05     -0.02
MF.007       0.03      0.05      0.06
MF.015       0.00      0.04      0.05
QEM.219     -0.02      0.02      0.01
QEM.234      0.41      0.15      0.02
QEM.277     -0.04      0.00      0.03
QEM.409      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

And this is the individual thresholds as a separate data frame `threshold`.

```
          V1    V2    V3
threshold 0.236 0.172 0.176
```

I have figured out the first part using an ifelse function.

```
Data.n$Peptide.1 <- ifelse(Data.t$Peptide.1 > threshold$V1, Data.t$Peptide.1, 0)
```

This would now give me:

```
        Peptide.1 
MF.001       0.00      
MF.006       0.00      
MF.007       0.00      
MF.015       0.00      
QEM.219      0.00      
QEM.234      0.41      
QEM.277      0.00      
QEM.409      0.00
```

But now, I would like to apply the individual thresholds to all columns, ie `threshold$V2` to `Data.t$Peptide.2` and so on. I know I can do this individually, but I have 84 columns in totals. I will also have many more of these dataframes in the future, so I thought it will be helpful to write a loop.

Could I please get some help with this?

I am sure it's a super easy thing, but I tried writing lots of different `for` loops and all failed miserably.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the number of rows of  `threshold` equal to `Data.t` and compare the dataframes.

```
result <- Data.t * +(Data.t > threshold[rep(1, nrow(Data.t)), ])
```

`+(Data.t > threshold[rep(1, nrow(Data.t)), ])` part gives 1/0 values. So if value in `Data.t` is greater than corresponding `threshold` 1 is returned or else 0. These values are then multiplied with `Data.t` so values larger than threshold are kept as it is and smaller than threshold are turned to 0 avoiding the use of `ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronak! It works beautifully, and it's a very clever alternative as well! Just wondering though if this could be easily incorporated in a loop as well? Seeing that I might have many Data and Threshold spreadsheets in the future.

Comment: So you mean to do this for multiple datasets in a list? You could use `Map` to do that. Yes, `for` loop can be used as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ronak! Do you mind quickly showing me how exactly would you write that either using Map or a for loop? I am still very new in writing loops. Thanks again!

Comment: You should probably ask that as a new question but let me quickly show it to you here. If your list of `Data.t` is called `list_data`  and list of `threshold` is called `list_threshold` you could do `result <- Map(function(x, y) x * +(x > y[rep(1, nrow(x)), ]), list_data, list_threshold)`

Comment: If speed is an issue then you should consider using:`Data.t * t(t(Data.t) > unlist(threshold))` instead of the `rep` part